# How to set value of thr root element in XML file using LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

My XML file is of the form:

```
 "<TestFile fileext="C:\TestFiles\TestFile2.txt">

 </TestFile>"
```

Here the root element is "TestFile". My task is to create a new XML of this form for which the query I am using is:

```
  XDocument doc = new XDocument(
           new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
           new XComment("This is a medtata file of the file " + args[0]),
           new XElement("TestFile",path));
```

But instead of

```
 "<TestFile fileext="C:\TestFiles\TestFile2.txt">

 </TestFile>"
```

, the output is

```
 "<TestFile>C:\TestFiles\TestFile2.txt</TestFile>"
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: I got my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931650/adding-elements-to-an-xml-file-in-c-sharp

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
       new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
       new XComment("This is a medtata file of the file " + args[0]),
       new XElement("TestFile",new XAttribute("filetext", path)));
```

If you wanna add some value inside add next argument in XElement

Exmaple

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
           new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
           new XComment("This is a medtata file of the file " + args[0]),
           new XElement("TestFile",new XAttribute("filetext", path), "something"));
```