# Adding and removing XDocument elements and their childs with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've been coding a program that uses XDocument to write XML files. The structure of the test program is:

```
<SchoolData storeName="mikveIsrael" location="mikve">
    <employee id="1">
        <personalInfo>
            <name>Ilan Berlinbluv</name>
            <zip>58505</zip>
        </personalInfo>
        <employeeInfo>
            <salary>5000</salary>
            <id>1</id>
        </employeeInfo>
    </employee>
    <employee id="2">
        <personalInfo>
            <name>Noam Inbar</name>
            <zip>58504</zip>
        </personalInfo>
        <employeeInfo>
            <salary>4500</salary>
            <id>2</id>
        </employeeInfo>
    </employee>
    <employee id="3">
        <personalInfo>
            <name>Adi Raiten</name>
            <zip>58503</zip>
            </personalInfo>
        <employeeInfo>
            <salary>5000</salary>
            <id>3</id>
        </employeeInfo>
    </employee>
</SchoolData>
```

So far, my test program writes that to Employee.xml on my desktop. I can also read the data from XML using `XDocument.Load()`, and parse different information. However I don't know how to add or remove elements (the element I want to add is `<employee>`, which contains all the elements such as name and such. Can someone point me in the right direction on how this is done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding elements to an xml file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931650/adding-elements-to-an-xml-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding elements to XML is pretty straightforward. Using the right indentation you can even see the XML structure in your code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

doc.Root.Add(new XElement("employee", new XAttribute("id", 42),
                 new XElement("personalInfo",
                     new XElement("name", "Arthur Dent"),
                     new XElement("zip", "00000")),
                 new XElement("employeeInfo",
                     new XElement("salary", 0),
                     new XElement("id", 3))));

doc.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: What about removing elements? I'm going to scrap the `id` attribute and use the `name` element to see which elements to delete. Is there a way to find what element has a specific name and delete it? (delete the `employee` element)