# object reference not set to an instance of an object xml C# and adding some node in xml file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

this is simple code for using xml in C#. I want to add data like

```
<table1 name="something">
   <column1 someattribute="something"> actualname </column>
</table1>
```

then I want to add this element into XDocument's Object

```
XDocument document;
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   document = new XDocument();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //document = new XDocument();
   XElement elem = new XElement("table1");
   elem.Add(new XAttribute("TableName", textBox1.Text));
   elem.Add(new XElement("Column1",new XAttribute("Someattribute", somevalue));
   document.Element("table1").Add(elem);//throws exception object refernce not set ..."
}
```

I have tried the following code [Adding elements to an xml file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931650/adding-elements-to-an-xml-file-in-c-sharp)   but it throws an exception of "object reference not set to an instance of an object xml C#"
Please help
P.S: suppose there are many columns in table1 then first I want to accmulate each column then add it to xdocument and then there is table2 and I want to do the same thing with him.

Comment: Looks like a basic NullRef exception. Check that `document.Element("Table")` is returning an actual value eg `var tableElement = document.Element("Table"); tableElement.Add(elem)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no `table1` elements in your XML structure. This means that your `document.Element("table1")` table returns `null`, and therefore there is an exception when you call `.Add(elem)` on it.

Debugging `NullReferenceExceptions` is very basic most of the time and these problems can easily be solved simply by stepping through the code with a debugger.

For reference, the `Element` method

> Gets the first (in document order) child element with the specified XName.

Which is why you get a `null`. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

When you initialize the form, you create an empty document like so `new XDocument()`. Then, in your button click, you are trying to add a new element **as a child to `table1`** by using the selector `document.Element("table1")`. That is the issue, your `XDocument` is empty! You would need to first create a `table1` element or instead add your `elem` object directly to the document.

Meaning you can either do this to make sure `table1` exists:

```
document = XDocument.Parse("<table1></table1>);
```

or change your click method to add directory to the root of the document:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //document = new XDocument();
   XElement elem = new XElement("table1");
   elem.Add(new XAttribute("TableName", textBox1.Text));
   elem.Add(new XElement("Column1",new XAttribute("Someattribute", somevalue)));
   document.Add(elem);
}
```

Comment: Please explain I'm Learning XML through C#
Can you Please read the code once again

Comment: @user3113029 I added some details

Comment: how would you create the following code thorugh C#
<db name="something">
   <table1 name="something">
     <column1 someattribuename="something" > Data </column>
    </table>
</DB>
first we add some root by xelement elem = new xelement("DB" , new Xattribute("Name", someinput"); Then what
Im confuse with adding properly new nodes and modify exsiting nodes
Thanks!

Comment: What are you confused about? See what I added to my question you should find your answer there.

Comment: I got it but
if I want to add new element inside this "elem" then what should I do?

Comment: Well now that `table1` is created you can use the `Element("table1")` method and expect a result. Read on Linq To XML and on the methods and objects related to `XDocument`. It should give you the knowledge needed to do these basic operations.

Answer (score 4):

Every XML document/structure has to have one unique node/tag, called the *root* node, that should exist only once in every document. So a proper xml can look like this - one root, but many nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root name="example">
  <node attribute="1">information 1</node>
  <node attribute="2">information 2</node>
</root>
```

There are two possibilities to access the root element using LINQ2XML: [XDocument.Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [XDocument.Element("elementName")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Knowing this and using the given xml code, it should be easy to follow the following example, that uses LINQ2XML to manipulate the xml code:

```
// every XML structure has to have a root node, that is unique
// and should exists only once!
var xmlCode = @"<root name=""example"">
                    <node attribute=""1"">information 1</node>
                    <node attribute=""2"">information 2</node>
                </root>";
// load the example xml code
var document = XDocument.Parse(xmlCode);
// create new attribute object
var newAttribute = new XAttribute("attribute", "3");
// create new node / column object with the newly created attribute and set the content of the node
var newNode = new XElement("node", newAttribute, "information 3");
// add the newly created node to the XML Document root
// in LINQ2XML the root node can be accessed via the Root property
// of an XDocument object
document.Root.Add(newNode);
// alternative: find the document root node using its name, in this example the node 
// is named "root" and add the new element to it!
// document.Element("root").Add(newNode);
```

The output is:

```
<root name="example">
  <node attribute="1">information 1</node>
  <node attribute="2">information 2</node>
  <node attribute="3">information 3</node>
</root>
```

In your question *table1* is *root* in this xml code and *column1* equivalent is *node*.

If you are going to use [LINQ2XML, than have a look at all methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the framework offers.

Answer (score 0):

Throw exception, because at the time the item is inserted in the XDocument(document) XElement (elem) element Element("Table") does not exist yet

Comment: Means I'm not inserting anything ??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add your now element to an existing element that doesn't exist:

```
document.Element("table1").Add(elem);//throws exception object refernce not set ..."
```

The `table1` element hasn't been added to the document yet.  You need to reference the appropriate parent element.  To add it to the root element use

```
document.Root.Add(elem);
```

Comment: First 
document.Root.Add(elem);
then docemnt.Element("Column", someattribute..)
isn't so??

Comment: No, add it to the appropriate parent. You're tryting to add the `table1` element that you're _creating_ to an _existing_ `table1` element that apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: if I want to add some child in an existing node
then what would you prefer?

Comment: It's more efficient to build up the entire tree then add it to the document - you're just trying to add it to a location that doesn't exist yet because _you haven't added it yet_.