# how to change a line(Config) in XML file

Tags: c#, xml, file

I need to change the second line to `config schema ="xxx.xsd"` how can I do that ?

```
1<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
2<**config**>
3<maketool-config>
.
.
.
</maketool-config>
</config>
```

here is the code :

```
 XElement triggerRoot = new XElement("config",
                new XElement("maketool-config",
            );
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931650/adding-elements-to-an-xml-file-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp

Comment: I want to change the configurations and already checked those links

Comment: Do you want to insert `schema="xxx.xsd"` or `xmlns="xxx.xsd"`? The first one would be equivalent to the insertion of an attribute. The second is alternation of a namespace, which is much more complex, because changing this line might (or might not, depending on your needs) change all other elements as well.

Comment: If you want to change an existing file, you should not create a new `XElement`. You should load the XML into a `XDocument`.

Comment: yes I want to change an existing file and thanks , I fixed that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var triggerRoot = new XElement("config", new XElement("maketool-config", ""));
        var newAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("schema");
        newAttribute.Value = "xxx.xsd";
        triggerRoot.SetAttributeValue("schema", "xxx.xsd");
```

Comment: if you already loaded the document, simply call Attributes.Append(newAttribute) on the document root