# Put string to xml file

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I writing Android app on Xamarin (c#)

I have xml that writing to file

XML:

```
<Order 
    CallConfirm="1"
    PayMethod="Безнал" 
    QtyPerson="2" 
    Type="2" 
    PayStateID="0" 
    Remark="111111" 
    RemarkMoney="0" 
    TimePlan="" 
    Brand="1" 
    DiscountPercent="0" 
    BonusAmount="0"
    Department="">
       <Customer Login="dev.bohdan@gmail.com" FIO="Bohdan Trachuk"/>
       <Address 
          CityName="Київ" 
          StationName="" 
          StreetName="" 
          House="" 
          Corpus="" 
          Building="" 
          Flat="" 
          Porch="" 
          Floor="" 
          DoorCode=""/>         
       <Phone Code=" (0" Number="96) 717-19-02" />
       <Products/>
</Order>
```

I need to put this string `<Product Code="{ProductCode}" Qty="{QTY}" />` into `<Products> </Products>` block. And then change `{ProductCode}` and `{QTY}` values.

How to change I know and have code.
Like this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

var query = doc
    .Descendants("Product")
    .Where(p => (string) p.Attribute("Qty") == "{QTY}");

foreach (var element in query)
{
    element.SetAttributeValue("Qty", counttext.Text);
}

var query2 = doc
    .Descendants("Product")
    .Where(p => (string) p.Attribute("Code") == "{ProductCode}");

foreach (var element in query2)
{
    element.SetAttributeValue("Code", Code1);
}
```

How I can put string directly into this block?

Comment: Check this out [Adding elements to an XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931650/adding-elements-to-an-xml-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @dxcorzo Yes, but I need to add it directly to <Products></Products>
I
I don't want to change other xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much easier to create an `XElement` node for your `<Product>` with the correct values, then add it, rather than add it, then search for the node you just added to replace its values.  Thus:

```
var product = new XElement("Product", new XAttribute("Code", Code1), new XAttribute("Qty", counttextText));
var products = doc.Descendants("Products").First(); // Get the first Products node.  Throw an exception if not found.
products.Add(product);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cEe8w6).

Comment: Thank's. Will test it.