# Find an XElement with a certain attribute name and value

Tags: xml

I am using below XML file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Help>
      <P_Types>
        <P_Type id="My_id">
              <Commands>
                  <Command id="cmd1">"cmd1" will execute first command.</Command>
                  .
                  .
              </Commands>
              <flds>
                  <fld id="fld1">Enter fld1</fld>
                  <fld id="NEW_FLD">Enter NEW_FLD.</fld>
                  .
                  .
              </flds>
        </P_Type>
        <P_Type id="another_id>
            <commands>
                <command id="XMZ">
                  .
                  .
            </command>
            <flds>
                <fld id="ABC">...... </fld>
                  .
                  .
            <flds>
        </P_Type>
      </P_Types>        
    </Help>
```

My code is returning me fld id's and command id's. I need "P_Type's id, where I am going to check if (P_type == "My_id") . if yes then will take action1 else action2.

My code current code is as below.
Help will be highly appreciated.
htHelp & htCmdHelp are declared as  Hashtable

```
HelpCollection hlpCol = null;
IEnumerable<XElement> helpLs = from helpEls in xml.Descendants("P_Type") select helpEls;
if (helpLs.Count() > 0)
    foreach (XElement el in helpLs)
    {
        if (el.HasElements)
        {
            hlpCol = new HelpCollection();
            foreach (XElement v in el.Elements("flds").Elements())
                hlpCol.htHelp.Add(v.Attribute("id").Value, v.Value);
            foreach (XElement c in el.Elements("Commands").Elements())
                hlpCol.htCmdHelp.Add(c.Attribute("id").Value, c.Value);
            helpColl.Add(el.Attribute("id").Value, hlpCol);
       }
   }
```

Comment: dont understand - where you stuck? what have you tried so far? 
''"I need "P_Type's id, where I am going to check if (P_type == "My_id")"'' - wouldn't it be the same??

Comment: I need to add new node <fld id="NEW_FLD">Enter NEW_FLD.</fld> which will be child of <flds> and <P_Type id="My_id">

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931650/adding-elements-to-an-xml-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Sorry My previous question might not be correct. I need to put old node and new note in Hashtable which I am going to use further to display content on aspx file.