# Insert a string in a particular position into an other string

Tags: c#, xml

I am work on some innerxml of an XML document.

I have to concat several parts.

I have this:

```xml
<TRANFSERT><GOOD></GOOD></TRANSFERT>
```

I want to insert another part, `<GOOD></GOOD>`, before `</TRANSFERT>`.

I tried this:

```cs
int pos = xmldoc.indexOf("</GOOD>");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(xmlFinal);
sb.Append(xmlModifiee,pos,xmlModifiee.length);
xmlFinal = sb.ToString();
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I add a small part of XML in other XML?

Comment: You should use the right tools, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931650/adding-elements-to-an-xml-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: You already have an XML NodeTree. So insert Nodes, not raw text in text. (I guess that's what Tim's link will show you)

Comment: Not like this. You modify the XmlDocument/XDocument nodes. What you're trying to do is insert children to the `GOOD` node

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't interact with XML like with ordinary string.
Use provided `System.Xml.XmlDocument` or `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` classes:

Ordinary XmlDocument single node selection and appending new element to it:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load("YourFile.xml");

XmlNode goodNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("TRANSFERT/GOOD");

XmlNode nodeToInsert = xmlDocument.CreateElement("INSERTEDNODE");    
goodNode.AppendChild(nodeToInsert);
```

Ordinary XmlDocument iterating by nodes to find necessary (be aware for many-childed nodes) and add new child node to it:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load("YourFile.xml");

foreach (XmlNode rootNode in xmlDocument.ChildNodes)
{
    if (rootNode.Name == "TRANSFERT")
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in rootNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (childNode.Name == "GOOD")
            {
                XmlNode nodeToInsert = xmlDocument.CreateElement("INSERTEDNODE");
                childNode.AppendChild(nodeToInsert);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Linq to XML variant:

```
 XDocument xDoc =  XDocument.Load("YourFIle.xml");
 XElement rootElement = xDoc.Element("TRANSFERT");
 XElement goodElement = rootElement.Element("GOOD");
 goodElement.Add(new XElement("INSERTEDNODE"));
```

Simplified Linq to XML variant:

```
 XDocument.Load("YourFIle.xml").Element("TRANSFERT").Element("GOOD").Add(new XElement("INSERTEDNODE"));
```

EDITED: answering the question, example was rewrited from changing InnerText values to Append/Add new child element to GOOD node.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder.Append` can only be used to add something **to the end** of the string. To add something inside the string, use `StringBuilder.Insert` like this:

```cs
sb.Insert(pos, xmlModifiee);
```